# .net core api + jwt authentication + .net core mvc client

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, jwt

I have two projects, one is the API, the other one is the Client to consume the API. Both are .net core 3.1.
In API project I implemented JWT Authentication and have some methods with Authorize attribute (`[Authorize("Bearer")]`).

My problems starts in the Client project. I can authenticated in the API, but I want add the Authorize attribute to some methods in Client project.
I have a page (Results) the only authenticated users can acess, but the link to Results page is on the primary header menu. If the users attempt to step into the page I want redirect them to the login page.

My doubts are:

- Is this approach correct?
- How I add Authorize attribute to the controller method responsable to show the Results view? And `Authorize("Bearer")`?
- How I implement redirect always the user is not authorized?

If is needed more details or some implementation let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just add `[Authorize]` attribute is ok,no need `Authorize("Bearer").Refer to:https://stackoverflow.com/a/60255637/11398810.And for how to implement redirect,you could refer to:https://stackoverflow.com/a/46231552/11398810.

Comment: Hi @Rena, my JWT auth configuration is in API project and my IActionResult method is in Client project. If I add `[Authorize]` to my IActionResult I receive the error "InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. ". Even if I add the redirect that you mentioned above, it will never activated.